# Display message at Linux login

Tags: c, linux, authentication

I want to make a terminal appear each time I login into my user, with a message and with a specific size in terms of rows and columns.

My first approximation was to make a program in C that would create that terminal and print on it, and then make something to run the command at login, but I don't know how to do that. And maybe, when running the command it may run in background with no terminal showing up.

So, how can I achieve that?

This was my first try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

struct winsize w_old;

void reconfig_terminal () __attribute__ ((destructor)) {
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCSWINSZ, &w_old);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct winsize w_new;

    if (ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w_old) == -1)
        return 0;

    w_new = w_old;
    w_new.ws_row = 4;
    w_new.ws_col = 19;

    if (ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCSWINSZ, &w_new) == -1)
        return 0;

    printf("\n    Alvaro Rojo\n      MARICON");

    while (1) { /* Esperamos hasta el fin del mundo */ }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right, get the program working first, then running it at startup is a different (and pretty trivial) matter.

Comment: You mean, you log into the *graphical desktop environment*, it would open a terminal window? That's not at al what you're doing there...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I supossed it, that's why I said "And maybe, when running the command it may run in background with no terminal showing up". Thanks for confirming it :) How could I do it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1101747/how-to-run-a-bash-script-when-using-a-graphical-desktop-login

Answer (score 0):

add following line to your ~/.bashrc

echo "Welcome $(whoami)"

whatever the message you echo, it will display.